# Can't download Docker machine from github

Tags: curl, docker, docker-machine

When I try to download Docker machine as specified in Docker docs, I get the following error:

```
$curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.10.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine

curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I don't know much about curl and networking, any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is an alternative way to install docker machine, please suggest, the docs doesn't specify any other way for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try with http not https, it can be related to SSL cert:

curl -L http://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.10.0/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) > /tmp/docker-machine

Comment: thanks @EFREV123 , I did try using http, the command runs fine but the docker machine doesn't get installed.

Comment: Take a look at the complete command from  [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#installing-machine-directly):   
  chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine &&   
  sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine   it works for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a certificate issue.

Try running those commands from [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)

`$ sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common`

Comment: I tried the the command , but everything is already at the newest version.